# Two directives, respective pair of controllers and same templateUrl

Tags: angularjs

I am novice in AngularJS. I want to use one template for two directives. In deal, the first directive overrides the behavior of the second. But I've specified different controllers for each of them. I think the reason is isolation of scopes by controllers. I need that the first controller execute its own filterChanged() function and so does the second controller. Same with fields: montage, pay, cancel and inactivity. I tried to manipulate the scope (true, 'isolate', false, {}), transclude (true, false, 'element'), scope fields ('@', '=', '&'). 'controllerAs' and 'controllerBindTo' are unsuitable for my task, because I want to this throw separate controller files.

Help me plz. Hands fall.

Source code below.

filter.html

```
<div class="filter">
<p class="text-center"><b ng-bind="::title"></b></p>
<div class="contact-item-requires-filter">
    <div class="contact-item-require">
        <input id="contact-item-montage-filter" class="contact-item-require-montage" type="checkbox"
            ng-model="filter.montage"
            ng-change="filterChanged()">
        <label title="Монтажи" for="contact-item-montage-filter"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

directive1.js

```
angular.module('qualityControl')
.directive('requiresFilterDirective', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: '../templates/pages/quality/filter.html',
        controller: 'requiresFilterController'
    }
});
```

directive2.js

```
angular.module('qualityControl')
.directive('usersFilterDirective', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: '../templates/pages/quality/filter.html',
        controller: 'usersFilterController'
    }
});
```

UPDATED.

Comment: Both of your directives are using the same controllers and the same name for the directives. I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve but I would probably start from there.

Comment: Монтажи! Огонь !!! :)

Comment: Corrected directive2.js

Answer (score 0):

Add variable with '&', this is function declaration

```
.directive('requiresFilterDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                functionToCall: '&',
                someData: '='
            },
            templateUrl: '../templates/pages/quality/filter.html',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.functionToCall();
                console.log('scope.someData', scope.someData);
            }
        }
    })
```

Usage:

```
<requires-filter-directive function-to-call="myFunctOne()" some-data="yourJsonObject"></requires-filter-directive>

<requires-filter-directive function-to-call="myFunctTwo()" some-data="yourJsonObject"></requires-filter-directive>
```

And declare these functions in your main controller:

```
$scope.myFunctOne = function() {
    alert("111")
};

$scope.myFunctTwo = function() {
    alert("222")
};

$scope.yourJsonObject = {'aaa':123};
```